# Untar file using python no error/warnings?

Tags: python, tar

I am trying to untar files in *python*. I give my program a file path with the main directory of the file, which has 9 sub directories and python it loops throught them,finds the tar files with a certain name and untars them.

So my `output_text` file has my main directory,and i loop after that throught my `01-09` file numbers in that directory and *unzip* file with certain name in them.

I have written some code but what happens is **nothing, no errors, no warnings nothing** :

```
def main():
    output_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/clients_file.txt"
    path = []
    with open(output_path) as f:
        for exptini_path_raw in f:
            exptini_path = exptini_path_raw.strip()
            path.append(exptini_path)

for i in range(1,1):
    for j in range(0,len(path)):
        if i < 10:
            p = "/%s/0%d/middleware"%(path[j],i)
        else:
            p = "/%s/%d/middleware"%(path[j],i)
    for root, _, files in os.walk(p):
            for f in files:
                if not 'client-logs' or 'middleware-logs' in f:
                    continue
                print 'going to extract %s'%f
                f1 = os.path.join(p,f)
                tar = tarfile.open(f1)
                tar.extractall()
                tar.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Note:** Even what I print out does not appear, what could be the cause?

EDIT: I modified my code and now got this

```
File "unzip_files.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "unzip_files.py", line 40, in main
    tar = tarfile.open(f1)
  File
```

"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1672, in open
        raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
    tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully

This is my mdodified code:

import os
import os.path
import tarfile

```
def main():
    output_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/clients_file.txt"
    path = []
    with open(output_path) as f:
        for exptini_path_raw in f:
            exptini_path = exptini_path_raw.strip()
            path.append(exptini_path)
            print path

for i in range(1,10):
    print i
    for j in range(0,len(path)):
        print j
        if i < 10:
            p = "/%s/0%d"%(path[j],i)
        else:
            p = "/%s/%d"%(path[j],i)
        print p
        for root, _, files in os.walk(p):
            for f in files:
                if not 'client-logs' or 'middleware-logs' in f:
                    continue
                print 'going to extract %s'%f
                f1 = os.path.join(p,f)
                tar = tarfile.open(f1)
                tar.extractall()
                tar.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

NOTE : the file is a tgz file!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range(1,1):` does nothing. You won't get any iterations.

Give it a try:

```
>>> for i in range(1,1):
...     print i
... 
>>> for i in range(1,2):
...     print i
... 
1
```

I think you want something more like this:

**EDIT:** *I've fixed and tested the following.*

**untarscript.py**

```
import os, tarfile

def main():
    output_path = "/Users/rs/Documents/clients_file.txt"
    path = []
    with open(output_path) as f:
        for exptini_path_raw in f:
            exptini_path = exptini_path_raw.strip()
            print "Adding to path: {}".format(exptini_path)
            path.append(exptini_path)

    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(0,len(path)):
            p = "{}/{:0>2}/middleware".format(path[j], i)
            print "Path to search for tar files: {}".format(p)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
                for f in files:
                    print "Investigating file: {}".format(f)
                    if not ('client-logs' in f or 'middleware-logs' in f):
                        print "This file does not match expected file name...skipping: {}".format(f)
                        continue
                    print 'going to extract {} to folder {}'.format(os.path.join(p,f), p)
                    f1 = os.path.join(p,f)
                    tar = tarfile.open(f1)
                    tar.extractall(path=p)
                    tar.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`for i in range(1,10):` will give you the sub directory numbers 1 - 9.

`{:0>2}` will take the value of i and 0-pad it to be 2 digits.  Removed the `%` and used the newer [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Fixed the tabbing of the `for root, dir, files in os.walk(p):` line so that it will execute each time `p` gets updated.

Replaced `if not 'client-logs' or 'middleware-logs' in f:` with `if not ('client-logs' in f or 'middleware-logs' in f):` because the test for `middleware-logs` was failing.

Added `path=p` argument to `tar.extractall()` to ensure the tar file got extracted to the same folder in which it was found. You can remove this if it's not the desired behavior.

**Before executing untarscript.py:**

```
[root@joeyoung.io Documents]# pwd
/Users/rs/Documents
[root@joeyoung.io Documents]# ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Oct 27 15:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Oct 27 15:09 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   87 Oct 27 12:30 clients_file.txt
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Oct 27 12:37 exptini1
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Oct 27 12:37 exptini2
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Oct 27 12:37 exptini3
[root@joeyoung.io Documents]# cat clients_file.txt
/Users/rs/Documents/exptini1
/Users/rs/Documents/exptini2
/Users/rs/Documents/exptini3

(stackoverflow)[root@joeyoung.io Documents]# tree
.
|-- clients_file.txt
|-- exptini1
|   |-- 01
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 02
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 03
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 04
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 05
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 06
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 07
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 08
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   `-- 09
|       `-- middleware
|           `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|-- exptini2
|   |-- 01
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 02
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 03
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 04
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 05
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 06
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 07
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |-- 08
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   `-- 09
|       `-- middleware
|           `-- client-logs-archive.tar
`-- exptini3
    |-- 01
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 02
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 03
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 04
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 05
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 06
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 07
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |-- 08
    |   `-- middleware
    |       `-- client-logs-archive.tar
    `-- 09
        `-- middleware
            `-- client-logs-archive.tar
```

**After executing untarscript.py:**

```
(stackoverflow)[root@joeyoung.io Documents]# tree
.
|-- clients_file.txt
|-- exptini1
|   |-- 01
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_01
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 02
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_02
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 03
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_03
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 04
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_04
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 05
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_05
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 06
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_06
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 07
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_07
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 08
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini1_08
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   `-- 09
|       `-- middleware
|           |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|           `-- client-logs_exptini1_09
|               |-- test1.txt
|               |-- test2.txt
|               |-- test3.txt
|               |-- test4.txt
|               |-- test5.txt
|               |-- test6.txt
|               |-- test7.txt
|               |-- test8.txt
|               `-- test9.txt
|-- exptini2
|   |-- 01
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_01
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 02
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_02
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 03
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_03
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 04
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_04
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 05
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_05
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 06
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_06
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 07
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_07
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   |-- 08
|   |   `-- middleware
|   |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|   |       `-- client-logs_exptini2_08
|   |           |-- test1.txt
|   |           |-- test2.txt
|   |           |-- test3.txt
|   |           |-- test4.txt
|   |           |-- test5.txt
|   |           |-- test6.txt
|   |           |-- test7.txt
|   |           |-- test8.txt
|   |           `-- test9.txt
|   `-- 09
|       `-- middleware
|           |-- client-logs-archive.tar
|           `-- client-logs_exptini2_09
|               |-- test1.txt
|               |-- test2.txt
|               |-- test3.txt
|               |-- test4.txt
|               |-- test5.txt
|               |-- test6.txt
|               |-- test7.txt
|               |-- test8.txt
|               `-- test9.txt
`-- exptini3
    |-- 01
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_01
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 02
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_02
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 03
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_03
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 04
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_04
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 05
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_05
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 06
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_06
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 07
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_07
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    |-- 08
    |   `-- middleware
    |       |-- client-logs-archive.tar
    |       `-- client-logs_exptini3_08
    |           |-- test1.txt
    |           |-- test2.txt
    |           |-- test3.txt
    |           |-- test4.txt
    |           |-- test5.txt
    |           |-- test6.txt
    |           |-- test7.txt
    |           |-- test8.txt
    |           `-- test9.txt
    `-- 09
        `-- middleware
            |-- client-logs-archive.tar
            `-- client-logs_exptini3_09
                |-- test1.txt
                |-- test2.txt
                |-- test3.txt
                |-- test4.txt
                |-- test5.txt
                |-- test6.txt
                |-- test7.txt
                |-- test8.txt
                `-- test9.txt

84 directories, 271 files
```

Comment: Thank you! It says   p = "/%s/{0:0>2}/middleware"%(path[j],i)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: and it still does nothing,even if I keep all ur changes except the one at line 26 :(

Comment: I fixed and tested the whole script.  It works now with my new changes.